# How to correctly work with data from React Context in useEffect/useCallback-hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm using a React Context to store data and to provide functionality to modify these data.

Now, I'm trying to convert a Class Component into a Functional Component using React Hooks.

While everything is working as expected in the Class, I don't get it to work in the Functional Component.

Since my applications code is a bit more complex, I've created this small example ([JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Jens_Duttke/78y15o9p/)), which allows to reproduce the problem:

First the Context, which is the same for both, the Class and the Functional Component:

```js
const MyContext = React.createContext();

class MyContextProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.increase = this.increase.bind(this);
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            current: 0,
            increase: this.increase,
            reset: this.reset
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <MyContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
        );
    }

    increase (step) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            current: prevState.current + step
        }));
    }

    reset () {
        this.setState({
            current: 0
        });
    }
}
```

Now, here is the Class component, which works just fine:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.increaseByOne = this.increaseByOne.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        setInterval(this.increaseByOne, 1000);
    }

    render () {
        const count = this.context;

        return (
            <div>{count.current}</div>
        );
    }

    increaseByOne () {
        const count = this.context;

        if (count.current === 5) {
            count.reset();
        }
        else {
            count.increase(1);
        }
    }
}
MyComponent.contextType = MyContext;
```

The expected result is, that it counts to 5, in an interval of one second - and then starts again from 0.

And here is the converted Functional Component:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const count = React.useContext(MyContext);

    const increaseByOne = React.useCallback(() => {
        console.log(count.current);

        if (count.current === 5) {
            count.reset();
        }
        else {
            count.increase(1);
        }
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(increaseByOne, 1000);
    }, [increaseByOne]);

    return (
        <div>{count.current}</div>
    );
}
```

Instead of resetting the counter at 5, it resumes counting.

The problem is, that `count.current` in line `if (count.current === 5) {` is always `0`, since it does not use the latest value.

The only way I get this to work, is to adjust the code on the following way:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const count = React.useContext(MyContext);

    const increaseByOne = React.useCallback(() => {
        console.log(count.current);

        if (count.current === 5) {
            count.reset();
        }
        else {
            count.increase(1);
        }
    }, [count]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect');

        const interval = setInterval(increaseByOne, 1000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, [increaseByOne]);

    return (
        <div>{count.current}</div>
    );
}
```

Now, the `increaseByOne` callback is recreated on every change of the context, which also means that the effect is called every second.
The result is, that it clears the interval and sets a new one, on every change to the context (You can see that in the browser console).
This may work in this small example, but it changed the original logic, and has a lot more overhead.

My application does not rely on an interval, but it's listening for an event. Removing the event listener and adding it again later, would mean, that I may loose some events, if they are fired between the remove and the binding of the listener, which is done asynchronously by React.

Has someone an idea, how it is expected to React, to solve this problem without to change the general logic?

I've created a fiddle here, to play around with the code above:
https://jsfiddle.net/Jens_Duttke/78y15o9p/

Answer (score 4):

First solution is to put data is changing through time into `useRef` so it would be accessible by reference not by closure(as well as you access actual `this.state` in class-based version)

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const countByRef = React.useRef(0);
    countByRef.current = React.useContext(MyContext);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
          const count = countByRef.current;

          console.log(count.current);

          if (count.current === 5) {
                count.reset();
          } else {
            count.increase(1);
          }
      }, 1000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>{countByRef.current.current}</div>
    );
}
```

Another solution is to modify `reset` and `increase` to allow functional argument as well as it's possible with `setState` and `useState`'s updater.

Then it would be

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    count.increase(current => current === 5? 0: current + 1);
  }, 1000);
}, [])
```

PS also hope you have not missed clean up function in your real code:

```
useEffect(() => {
 const timerId = setInterval(..., 1000);
 return () => {clearInterval(timerId);};
}, [])
```

otherwise you will have memory leakage

Comment: I had already tried a similar solution using the useRef-hook, but I was not aware that I need to set `countByRef.current = React.useContext(MyContext);` instead of simply doing `const countByRef = React.useRef(React.useContext(MyContext));`. Thanks for clarifying that!  
So I assume that means, there is no simpler solution to access the Context without either to modify the `MyContextProvider` source code, or to use `useRef()`, which adds some more overhead to the code?

Comment: @JensDuttke, your deferred function creates closure in the moment of declaration and `useRef` and accessing things by reference are just to avoid using closure. Third alternative is relying on closure, recreating callback on each render and use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. But it would need much more code to handle that and also it would require even more code to handle case when value has been updated outside timer so you have to re-create timer(with up-to-date callback and smaller delay).

Answer (score 0):

If the `increaseByOne` function doesn't need to know the actual `count.current`, you can avoid recreating it. In the context create a new function called `is` that checks if the `current` is equal a value:

```
is = n => this.state.current === n;
```

And use this function in the `increaseByOne` function:

```
if (count.is(5)) {
    count.reset();
}
```

Example:

```js
const MyContext = React.createContext();

class MyContextProvider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }

  increase = (step) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      current: prevState.current + step
    }));
  }

  reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      current: 0
    });
  }

  is = n => this.state.current === n;

  state = {
    current: 0,
    increase: this.increase,
    reset: this.reset,
    is: this.is
  };
}

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const { increase, reset, is, current } = React.useContext(MyContext);

  const increaseByOne = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (is(5)) {
      reset();
    } else {
      increase(1);
    }
  }, [increase, reset, is]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(increaseByOne, 1000);
  }, [increaseByOne]);

  return (
    <div>{current}</div>
  );
}

const App = () => (
  <MyContextProvider>
    <MyComponent />
  </MyContextProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution is really nice, but isn't there any way, where I can solve the problem within the `MyComponent` component?

Is my definition of the Context wrong? I do it exactly, like it's done in the React documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component
Defining a property which contains a value, and providing a method which allows to change this value. There is no additional method to read this value, or any hint that such a method would be required if I'm using React Hooks.

Comment: The main idea with hooks is that everything is re-created when the component is re-rendered, unless it's memoized (`useMemo`, `useCallback`), or is a reference (`useRef`). In this case the memoized function is dependant on the context, which changes all the time. One solution is to use ref. Another, is to make the `useCallbac()` dependant on things that don't actually change - the functions from the context. I've updated the answer a bit to demonstrate that.